# ag-grid + valuegetter + row grouping

Tags: ag-grid

ag-grid valuegetter + row grouping, on cell click need to get params data.

In case of header & other cells except grouped row we are getting params data.

column definition of ag-grid looking like below:

```js
const scopeOutCurrIndex = function (col, rSeg, isPVInColSegment) {
                    return function (params) {
                       return params.data;          }
                };

                const colDefObj: any = {};
                // for E-NG-GRID
                colDefObj['rowGroup'] = true;
                colDefObj['hide'] = true;

                colDefObj.headerName = this.segLabelMap
                    ? this.gridUtilService.getSegmentLabel(rSegments[i], this.segLabelMap)
                    : rSegments[i];
                colDefObj["isRowSegment"] = true;
                colDefObj["headerId"] = rSegments[i];

                //Set width for column
                colDefObj["width"] = this.calColumnWidth(colDefObj.headerName);

                colDefObj["moduleId"] = moduleIds ? moduleIds[0] : moduleIds;
                colDefObj.valueGetter = scopeOutCurrIndex(rSegments[i], rSegments, this.isPVInColSegment);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const scopeOutCurrIndex = function (col, rSeg, isPVInColSegment) {
                return function (params) {
                   return params.node.allLeafChildren[0].data;}
            };
```

> We can get data from leaf children, ag-grid provide flexible to get data from leaf children.